# Usage of addressing, locating, identifying and specifying

Tags: word-usage

It seems I have a problem in using some verbs like *addressing*, *locating*, *identifying* and *specifying*.

In this sentence:

> However, the main drawback of the approaches that rely on the HTML structure to identify objects is the lack of flexibility. They may require the use of absolute HTML paths to **(address/locate/identify/specify/specify the address of/specify the location of)** a data item. This approach is likely to fail when the target HTML page changes.

I know that identify fits, but how about the others?

I thought of **address** in this context: 'to find, or to specify the address of something', but it seems this means just 'talking to a certain individual', or 'trying to solve a problem'.

**locate** again to specify the location, but it seems this means 'to find the location'.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the HTML path is something that *specifies* the *location* of an item. So

> They may require the use of absolute HTML paths to locate/specify a data item.

is certainly correct. They even are a better fit than *identify*, which has the connotation of 'you *already have* a data item, but don't know what it is exactly.'

*Address* is more often used (as a verb) for real-world addresses and the subject is usually a person then (e.g. 'I address this letter to you.')